# Why are my UITextFields Null after presenting the camera (or image picker)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a number of UIText Fields that are returning Null after the camera or image picker has been presented. How do I retain the text in these text fields?

Use Flow

User inputs text into text fields --> User chooses a picture to save along with the text ---> user taps save button, data is saved to coredata.

When no image is added the data saves fine, but when the camera is accessed the text fields get reset to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the information of the text fields in variables and then re-load them into the text fields upon

```
viewWillAppear
```